# Two foreach loops with same variable names break the order of elements

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Here is my code:

```
foreach($datawallright['adds'] as &$ad){
    $ad['img'] = get_ad_pic_url($this->em->getReference("models\MmAds",$ad['id']),'/crop_');
    $ad['description'] = ucfirst(strip_tags(html_entity_decode(mb_strtolower(str_replace(array("___","---"),"",$ad['description']), "UTF-8"))));
    $ad['titleurl'] = title_url($ad['title']);
}

foreach($datawallright['adds'] as $ad){

    $this->load->view("view_wallpage_add",array("ad"=>$ad,"isuserwall"=>$isuserwall));
}
```

I have two for loops going through the same array. The variables assigned in this two for loops are the same. The weird thing is when it iterates through the second for loop. The first n-1 element are correct, but in the place of the last element the element that is one before last appeares. I can do it all in one for loop. I can change the name of the variable $ad and then it works fine, but I want to know what happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happened is that the first loop iterates by reference, so when the second attempts to assign "the current item" to `$ad` it actually updates your array contents in addition to updating `$ad`.

The simplest fix is to add an `unset ($ad)` immediately after the first `foreach` so that PHP will not consider the name `$ad` a reference from that point onward.

The need to do this (or else suffer from hidden updates to the reference later on) is one of the ugliest things that can bite you in PHP; personally I am very religious about appending an `unset` after iterating by reference, even if that's the last statement in a function.

Comment: `array_map` would be an alternative that does not require `unset` after usage.

Comment: @Yoshi: Sure. One could also `foreach` with a key as well and do `$arr['adds'][$key]['img'] = ...`.